# Multiprocessing in Python to find prime numbers

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

In Python 3 I have this assignment where I need to find prime numbers in a interval `[a,b]` using multiprocessing.

Let's take as an example the interval [0,30] and with the use of 3 processes I have three intervals `[ai,bi]` : `[0.10]` ,`[10,20]` , `[20,30]`

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def isprime(num):
  if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) != 0:
               pass
       else:
           return num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result = pool.map(isprime, range(0,30))
    finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")
    print(result)
```

This is the outpot expected:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

This is what I get:

```
[None, None, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems:

1. Your `isprime` function will implicitly return `None` for arguments <= 1 but otherwise will always execute the `else` clause of your `for` statement and return the passed argument.
2. On the assumption that `isprime` will return the passed argument if it is prime or `None` if it is not, then you need to filter out `None` returned values from `isprime`.
3. You didn't actually solve the problem by breaking up the interval into ranges as you indicated was going to be your approach. I will address this in my comments following the code.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def isprime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return None
    for i in range(2, num):
         if (num % i) == 0:
            return None
    else:
        return num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, pool.map(isprime, range(0,30))))
    finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```None
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

**General Comments**

Your `isprime` function could be greatly improved (do a Google for a better implementations). For example:

```py
def isprime(num):
    from math import sqrt, floor

    if num < 2: return None
    if num == 2: return num
    if num % 2 == 0: return None
    for d in range(3, floor(sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        if num % d == 0: return None
    return num
```

But as you see, as the argument `n` increases the more iterations of the main loop are required to prove that the passed argument is prime.

The way you *could* handle this problem is to implement some version of the [Sieve of Eraosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm, which is efficient in producing a series of prime numbers and you would then pass to this function a *range* of numbers between which the sieve function would return all the primes it found within that range. You would, of course, break up your initial `range(0, 30)` into a list of 3 subranges, i.e. `[range(0, 10), range(10, 20), range(20, 30)]`, which would be passed to your `map` method.

But even the standard Sieve algorithm must start generating primes starting with 2 so even when you pass the argument `range(10, 20)` to it, the function would have to duplicate work that is being done when the argument `range(0, 10)` is being passed.

**So using multiple calls to a `isprime` method is not efficient for finding a range of primes but a Sieve algorithm gains nothing from a multiprocessing implementation (multiprocessing actually hurts performance). The best way to solve this problem would be with a non-multiprocessing Sieve.**